# Decoding exponential formula in VB

Tags: vb.net, math, checkbox, algebra, exponent

I am working on a program that allows the user to set an automatic task to run at certain times.

Here is an example of what the day of week selection looks like:

[image]

Each day is assigned a value of  2 ^ (x - 1), with x being the day number (Sun=1, Mon=2, Tue=3, etc..)

Then, the code goes through and calculates the sum of all the checked boxes to get a single numeric value that is stored in the database.

For example, if all the boxes are checked, the final value would be 1+2+4+8+16+32+64 = 127.

Here's what the VB code looks like:

```
If mycheckbox.Checked = True Then
    dowVal = dowVal + 2 ^ (x - 1)
End If
```

This repeats for every checkbox, substituting x for the day number and mycheckbox for each day's unique checkbox id. Once it runs though all 7 days, dowVal is the final value that gets sent to the database.

Generating the dowVal based on the checkboxes is easy enough, but how would I go about reversing this process?

Given a single dowVal, I need to go and programmatically check all the corresponding boxes and produce the exact same combination of checked boxes that were used to generate dowVal in the first place.

I initially tried using the inverse of the IF statement above like so:

```
 If dowVal = 2 ^ (x - 1) Then
            mycheckbox.Checked = True
 End If
```

Obviously this only works if a single checkbox is checked because it doesn't account for the summed values.

The only way I can think to do it would be a massive set of IF statements that account for all possible permutations, but this wouldn't work for other portions of the program that use this same formula such as minute of day, because that has 60 checkboxes and the number of combinations would be exponentially insane.

How would I go about decoding dowVal and translating that back into checked boxes that does not involve an exponential amount of cases?

Comment: What you want is generally known as [bit operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation) (and they can be done easier than using explicit exponentiation, since all your operations use base 2). Read up on the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Is this for homework? becuase there are a million other solutions that would be easier than how you are going about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wont give you the full answer becuase I am assuming this is for homework but I will give you a hint.

Start backwards.

If your number is 77

Start with 64. 64 fits into 77, which means you are left with 13 - then keep going backwards until you are left with the correct days (64,8,4,1).

Good Luck

```
Dim num = 77

for x as integer = {64,32,16,8,4,2,1,}
    if num - x >= 0 then
         select case num
              case 64 : checkbox64.checked = true
              case 32 : checkbox32.checked = true
              'blah blah 
         end select
         num -= x
    end if
next
```

Comment: This is not homework. This is for work and I would really appreciate and actual solution instead of hints. I know this seems like a roundabout way to do this but its a long story and involves preserving legacy software behavior to be compatable during a large database conversation. Thanks.

Comment: Jesus, someone actually decided to code this? why wouldnt they just use 1,2,3,4,5,6,7? ... Essentially the above is the answer, just make a for loop and check the boxes using case select.

Comment: @Nefariis This is an extremely common way of storing multiple Boolean flag values in a single variable.  This won't likely be the last time you see the pattern. Using numbers that are powers of 2 lets them stack together without interfering with each other, as each "power" lines up exactly with one of the bits when the number is converted to binary.

Comment: For example, say you wanted to set the first and second bit flags. using 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 you would add them together and get 3.  When you decode that, does it mean 1+2 or just 3?  When you use powers of 2 you have 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256 where 1+2=3 which is unambiguously 1+2 (as there is no "3" in the source values conflict with)

Comment: no no, I would just use 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 to correspond to the days - thus 135 would just be sunday, tuesday, thursday - no math required... or use q,w,e,r,t,y,u ... having seven items in a list does not necessitate using base 2.

Comment: I am trying to replicate something that was written like 15 years ago. We are currently in the process of migrating from an ancient no-name database to MySQL, and eventually re-write our software to be modernized. In the meantime, we need to reach an interim period where the old software is running on the new DB. This particular application was unable to be converted 'as is' due to our old software's inability to handle massive integers. I have no idea why this was designed this way in the first place, all I know is that I need to maintain the exact inputs and outputs as the original.

Comment: Also I should add that this functionality isn't just for day of week, I only chose that for my example because it is the smallest out of all places that follow this pattern. The largest is "minute of hour" where there are 60 checkboxes, so the permutations get really big. The pattern is continued for day of month, month of year, hour of day, and minute of hour.

Comment: Gotcha, well the above code will get you there regardless of the amount of entries - that's one of the things that base 2 has going for it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try it when I go back to work tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is ideal for a "Flags Enum".  You create an enumeration for each day of the week with values of powers of 2.  Then cast the encoded data in to  a variable of the Enumeration type.  Now you can just do this:

```
dim days as DaysOfWeek = ctype(value,DaysOfWeek)
if days.HasFlag(DaysOfWeek.Monday) then ...
```

More information can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx).